# Get ride of extra whitespace above/below 'code' tags

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out where the whitespace is coming from, above and below these `<code>` tags in HTML.  It doesn't appear to be margin or padding.  In the example below both are set to 0, and inspection w/ chrome dev tools doesn't seem to give any answers.  The extra space (green boxes above and below) show up in Chrome, FF, and IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/RPaLd/

```
<style type="text/css">
    section{
      border: thin solid black;
    }

    pre{
      border: thin solid red;
    }

    code{
      border: thin solid green;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px;
    }
</style>

<section>
    <pre>
        <code>
            // some code goes here
        </code>
    </pre>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: coming from the new line after your `//some code goes here`. see this edit: http://jsfiddle.net/RPaLd/1/

Comment: am so used to not giving newlines meaning in HTML that it didn't occur to me that the leading and trailing newlines in code would have just as much meaning as those in the rest of the code block. doh!  Post it as an answer and I'll mark as answered.

Comment: Inside of <pre> every caret return (new line) matters. Remove all.

Comment: **[CSS RESET](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to the rescue!** _This neutralizes html elements across browsers so you can specify your very own padding margin default heights, etc._

Comment: @MarkusHofmann - it's not the padding or margins causing the issue here. It's the line breaks and white space.

Comment: Looks like it. Have had a look at the answers and fiddles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newlines inside `<pre>` cause the extra space.

You can either remove the new lines or add `white-space: nowrap;` to your css.

See the edited fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RPaLd/1/

EDIT:

Also you can remove this:

```
margin: 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px;
```

from your CSS as that is the default for a code block.

Answer (score 4):

The whitespace is in your code tags.  Here's how it would look with no whitespace:

```
<pre><code>// some code goes here</code></pre>
```

Code is an inline element and will preserve those spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to `pre` CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/RPaLd/3/

Comment: Only problem with that is I lose the newlines I *do* want to show in the code.

Comment: In that case just assign  `margin: 0px;padding: 0px;` to `pre` DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/RPaLd/4/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Didn't see that someone else had already posted exactly the same thing - sorry!

---

In `pre` tags all white space is preserved - remove the white space before and after the `<code>` tags:

```
<section>
    <pre><code>// some awesome code</code></pre>
</section>
```